# How to remove square brackets from name attribute in webform elements?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, webforms

Name attribute in rendered webform elements contain square brackets like `submitted[field_machine_name]`.

[image]

.

[image]

Is there a way to replace square brackets in the name, so the name attribute looks something like "field_machine_name", without breaking the webform submission handler?

Answer (score 1):

you can use hook_form_alter

Example D8

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id=='comment_comment_form') {

    $form['subject']['widget']['0']['value']['#name'] = 'field_machine_name';

  }

}
```

Example D7

```
function comment_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

 if ($form_id=='comment_node_article_form')        {
    $form['subject']['#name'] = 'field_machine_name';
 }

}
```